# SQL Server Query for two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tables: T1, T2:

T1:

ID, VAL

T2:
ID, ID2, VAL

T1:ID and T2:ID using same values. I need to connect above tables in this way:
T3: ID, ID2, T2VAL, T1VAL
where T3 kind of full join, but it should have all the ID2 from T2 for all ID in T1, even if there is no such ID,ID2 key in T2.

Example:

```
T1:
0, t1_val_0
1, t1_val_1
2, t1_val_2
3, t1_val_3

T2:
0, id2_0, t2_0_0
1, id2_0, t2_1_0
2, id2_0, t2_2_0
0, id2_1, t2_0_1


T3 as result of the query:
ID, ID2, T2VAL, T1VAL

0, id2_0, t2_0_0, t1_val_0
1, id2_0, t2_1_0, t1_val_1
2, id2_0, t2_2_0, t1_val_2
3, id2_0, null, t1_val_3
0, id2_1, t2_0_1, t1_val_0
1, id2_1, null, t1_val_1
2, id2_1, null, t1_val_2
3, id2_1, null, t1_val_3
```

So I need a query which can join two above tables and return result as described above.

Comment: @BillGregg, It is definitely not a LEFT JOIN. I don't know what is this.

Comment: @BillGregg look at the picture of the person, I doubt it if he is still getting homework :)

Answer (score 1):

So, this is really bizarre.... but if this is what you want, here's what I did to get it (using Common Table Expressions and Sub-Selects).  Given this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (ID int, t1 varchar(10))
CREATE TABLE T2 (ID int, id2 varchar(10), t2 varchar(10))
```

And then putting this data in it:

```
INSERT INTO T1 (ID, t1)
VALUES (0, 't1_val_0'),
(1, 't1_val_1'),
(2, 't1_val_2'),
(3, 't1_val_3')

INSERT INTO T2 (ID, id2, t2)
VALUES
(0, 'id2_0', 't2_0_0'),
(1, 'id2_0', 't2_1_0'),
(2, 'id2_0', 't2_2_0'),
(0, 'id2_1', 't2_0_1')
```

I used this SELECT to extract data in the format you wanted:

```
;WITH 
ID1S AS (
SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM T1
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM T2
),
ID2S AS (
SELECT DISTINCT ID2 FROM T2
),
AllIDs AS (
SELECT ID, ID2 FROM ID1S CROSS JOIN ID2S
)
SELECT a.ID, a.ID2,
       (SELECT t2 FROM T2 WHERE ID = a.ID AND id2 = a.ID2) AS T2Val,
       (SELECT t1 FROM T1 WHERE ID = a.ID)
  FROM AllIDs a
 ORDER BY a.ID2, a.ID
```

To walk you through it, the first CTE gets the complete set of all IDs, while the second CTE gets the complete set of all "id2s", the third produced a CROSS JOIN to get all the possible combinations of those IDs.  That gives you the first two columns.  The second two are then sub-selects back to the original tables to fill in the matching values, leaving NULL for any data that is missing.

Comment: Note that the three separate CTEs may be over-kill and could certainly be simplified, but I wanted to walk you through each step of what was going on, so it would be clear.  And this should perform well regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is correct with bigger set of data, but this will bring all the combinations of T1.id and T2.id2 and then show the data from T2 if it exists:

```
;with T (id2) as (
  select distinct id2 from T2)

select
  T1.id,
  T.id2,
  T2.tval2,
  T1.tval1
from
  T1
  cross join T
  left outer join T2 on
    T2.id = T1.id and T2.id2 = T.id2
```